# Generate random number to three digits with Norm_inv OR optimize the function

Tags: excel, vba, random

I wrote a macro to generate random number from sample.

The RNG code is:

```vb
For i = 6 To LR

    Set row = RANGE(Cells(i, 8), Cells(i, LC))

    prumer = Application.Average(row)
    smodch = Application.stdev(row)
    
    For A = B To LCNEW
        Cells(i, A).Value = Application.Norm_Inv(Rnd(), prumer, smodch)
        Cells(i, A).Value = Application.ROUND(Cells(i, A).Value, 3)
        Cells(i, A).NumberFormat = "0.000"
    Next A
    
Next i
```

It takes a row, calculates average and stdev and then does the stuff.

On my computer it runs quickly, like 5-10 sec for 80 rows with 10 numbers and calculating 100 more randomized.

On an older computer it runs like 5 minutes! How can I calculate norm inv only to three digits or optimize it?

The whole code:

```vb
Sub RNGTOX()

   Dim lastcell As RANGE
   Dim row As RANGE
   Dim i As Long
   Dim A As Long
   Dim B As Long
   Dim prumer As Variant
   Dim smodch As Variant
   Dim LR As Long
   Dim LC As Long
   Dim ocislovani As RANGE
   Dim sSIDE As Worksheet

If RANGE("H6").Value = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "Chybí data."
    Exit Sub
End If
            
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     
Set sSIDE = ActiveSheet
Set lastcell = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

LR = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
LC = Cells(6, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
B = LC + 1
LCNEW = RANGE("B2").Value + 7

If LCNEW <= LC Then
    MsgBox "Počet už je dosažený. Není třeba dopočítávat."
    Exit Sub
Else
End If

'ocislovani souboru
Set ocislovani = sSIDE.RANGE(sSIDE.Cells(5, 8), sSIDE.Cells(5, LCNEW))

counter_cisla = 1
For Each cell_a In ocislovani
    cell_a.Value = counter_cisla
    counter_cisla = counter_cisla + 1
Next cell_a

'i radek, A sloupec
For i = 6 To LR

    Set row = RANGE(Cells(i, 8), Cells(i, LC))

    prumer = Application.Average(row)
    smodch = Application.stdev(row)
    
    For A = B To LCNEW
        Cells(i, A).Value = Application.Norm_Inv(Rnd(), prumer, smodch)
        Cells(i, A).Value = Application.ROUND(Cells(i, A).Value, 3)
        Cells(i, A).NumberFormat = "0.000"
    Next A
    
Next i

RANGE("H6").Select
       
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It processes the range in memory, loading an array and its content is dropped at once in the appropriate range. Also, writing a value in a cell then round it, place it back and format **each cell** takes time...:

```
Sub RNGTOX()
   Dim lastcell As Range, row As Range, i As Long, A As Long, B As Long
   Dim prumer As Variant, smodch As Variant, LR As Long, LC As Long, LCNEW As Long
   Dim ocislovani As Range, sSIDE As Worksheet
        
  If Range("H6").Value = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "Chybí data."
    Exit Sub
  End If
     
 Set sSIDE = ActiveSheet
 Set lastcell = sSIDE.cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

 LR = sSIDE.cells(sSIDE.rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
 LC = sSIDE.cells(6, sSIDE.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 B = LC + 1
 LCNEW = sSIDE.Range("B2").Value + 7

If LCNEW <= LC Then
    MsgBox "Pocet už je dosažený. Není treba dopocítávat."
    Exit Sub
End If

 'ocislovani souboru
 Set ocislovani = sSIDE.Range(sSIDE.cells(5, 8), sSIDE.cells(5, LCNEW))
 ocislovani.Value = Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(ROW(1:" & LCNEW & "))")

 Dim rng As Range, arr
 Set rng = sSIDE.Range(sSIDE.cells(6, 8), sSIDE.cells(LR, LC))

 ReDim arr(1 To rng.rows.count, 1 To LCNEW - B + 1) 'redim the array to keep the processed values
 For i = 1 To rng.rows.count
    
    prumer = Application.Average(rng.rows(i))
    smodch = Application.StDev(rng.rows(i))
    
    For A = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)  'LCNEW
       arr(i, A) = Round(Application.Norm_Inv(Rnd(), prumer, smodch), 3) 'load the array (working in memory)
    Next A
 Next i

  'drop the array content, at once:
  With sSIDE.cells(6, B).Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2))
        .Value = arr
        .NumberFormat = "0.000"
  End With
 
 Range("H6").Select
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

The code is not tested, not having an appropriate environment, but (if I correctly understood your code logic) it should work.

Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: Wow it is so quick now. Works perfectly. Thank you a lot, I will study the code and try to understand the principle behind the optimization.

Comment: @Vecernice Glad I could help! If is something you do not understand, please do not hesitate to ask for clarifications. Basically, the code avoid processing a cell at a time, which is the major tame consuming, in your code circumstances. Also, writing an incremented number in each cell is not the fasted way. The above code uses `Evaluate` to place at once a built array...

Comment: @Vecernice And something else: I would like to tell you that we here, when somebody answer our question in a convenient way, way, we tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. If somebody else will search for a similar issue, he will know that the proposed solution works...

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I was a little bit stuned that you understood fully the purpose of the code so quick :) I am not advanced enough to understand the work with arrays properly to be honest, so there is big area for me to explore. The answer is accepted now, thank you for reminding.

Comment: Sorry for interrupting, But How do you understand the users own codes? If I left my own codes for a time (e.g one month) I found that I forgot some parts from it. I really admire your intelligence of understanding users codes 

Comment: @Leedo You are not interrupting anything... Any piece of code is written in a programing **language**. If you understand that specific language, it is not such a big deal to read it... If OP stated that it works but having efficiency problems, I only located the areas where the code has such problems and use more efficient ways. A piece of code, **returning the same** can be written in many ways. Usually, I am focusing on its speed, reliability and sometimes to its compactness. Looking better and easier to be understood. I also need to understand my own code, but I do the same: I read it. :)